# Is it possible to have multiple panels with varying widths in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a requirement to support push-style and overlay panels with variable widths in my desktop webapp and jQuery mobile comes so close, except for the lack of variable panel widths.

I have [seen](http://goo.gl/ayq6LH) various [answers](http://goo.gl/ODAtis) on StackOverflow explaining how to override all the CSS properties to change the width globally for all panels, but I need to specify a different width for individual panels.

Is this possible in jQuery Mobile? If not, I would be interested to know if this is an issue with JQM itself or a technical limitation in general related to the way CSS transitions work maybe?

Answer (score 0):

At this point it is not possible, at least not easily, you will need to heavily modify CSS to make it work. But to ask your question you can have panels with a varying width. If you need an example leave me a comment and I will make you one.

Or if you want to wait a bit, next jQuery Mobile version 1.4 will have this by default. Unfortunately alpha 1.4 will come out in next few days, so stable version will come in 1-1-5 months. If you are not ready to wait I will create you a working example with jQuery Mobile 1.3.2.

#### EDIT :

My bad, 1.4 alpha is out: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/07/25/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-4-0-alpha/

Comment: An example would be great, thanks!  Just to clarify, my requirement is to have two (or more) panels on the page, each with different widths.  I'm not sure if my original question was clear enough on that point?